# @ConditionalOnMissingBean can not be overridden

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and I'm wondering how `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` should be used?

Example configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAutoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@Import(MyAutoConfiguration.class)
public class AppConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo("some property");
  }
}
```

`AppConfiguration.class` and `MyAutoConfiguration.class` are in different modules.

Error:

> The bean 'foo', defined in class path resource [com/example/autoconf/configuration/AppConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/my/configuration/MyAutoConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

How to use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` without setting `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `MyAutoConfiguration` to be picked up by Spring Boot as auto-configuration it need to be declared in `META-INF/spring.factories` as below

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=x.y.z.MyAutoConfiguration
```

For more details related to custom auto-configurations have a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-locating-auto-configuration-candidates).

Comment: I do not need it to be "AutoConfiguration" and picked up without explicit `@Import`. On the contrary, I do NOT want it to be picked up by boot unless I use the `@Import`. But nevertheless, I have tried adding the `factories` file and I get the same behaviour.

Comment: I haven't removed `@Import`. Works fine with `factories`.
Still would like to know how to setup explicitly with `@Import`.

Comment: `@Import` treats the class as normal configuration & not as auto-configuration. For `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` to work the class need to be registered as auto-configuration. Thus the observed behavior.

Comment: Any particular reason why `@Import` is required / preferred when it is achieved via auto-configuration which is much cleaner & inline with spring boot principle of _convention over configuration_ ?

Comment: Just because with `@Import` you can see which custom configurations are used.

Answer (score 0):

Method I've used to solve "overriding" problem both with auto-configuration and with explicit configuration:

Shared module:

```
@Configuration
public class SharedAutoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

+

```
META-INF/spring.factories
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
        x.y.z.SharedAutoConfiguration
```

App with explicit configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AppSpecificConfiguration 
    extends SharedAutoConfiguration { // <== extends base configuration

  @Bean
  @Override // <== overrides
  public Foo foo() {
    return new AppSpecificFoo();
  }
}

@Import(AppSpecificConfiguration.class)
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class);
  }
}
```